# Exception with OpenCV4.5.5 DnnSuperResImpl - ReadModel (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a issue when using OpenCV dnn module.

Here are my settings:

1. Building OpenCV 4.5.5 with extra module opencv_contrib-4.x (clone from github)
2. Downloading EDSR_x4.pb and EDSR_x3.pb from [EDSR_tensorflow](https://github.com/Saafke/EDSR_Tensorflow/tree/master/models)
3. move .pb files to root directory of my project

However, no matter I used relative path or absolute path, readModel() failed for these two path:

```
DnnSuperResImpl sr;
sr.readModel ("EDSR_X4.pb");
sr.readModel ("C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\ZBAR_OpenCV4.5\\ZBAR_OpenCV4.5\\EDSR_x3.pb");
```

Results from using command "dir"

```
C:\Users\user\source\repos\ZBAR_OpenCV4.5\ZBAR_OpenCV4.5
2022/06/13  afternoon 01:39           201,562 EDSR_x3.pb
2022/06/13  afternoon 10:40           206,908 EDSR_x4.pb
2022/06/07  afternoon 11:37             3,124 ZBAR_OpenCV4.5.cpp
2022/06/07  afternoon 11:37               544 ZBAR_OpenCV4.5.h
2022/06/13  afternoon 02:05             8,719 ZBAR_OpenCV4.5Dlg.cpp
2022/06/13  afternoon 11:37             1,627 ZBAR_OpenCV4.5Dlg.h
```

Exception printed out:

```
code= -2
err= FAILED: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse GraphDef file: EDSR_x4.pb

func= cv::dnn::ReadTFNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie

line= 42

msg= OpenCV(4.5.5) C:\OpenCV4.5\opencv\sources\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_io.cpp:42: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse GraphDef file: EDSR_x4.pb in function 'cv::dnn::ReadTFNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie'


what= OpenCV(4.5.5) C:\OpenCV4.5\opencv\sources\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_io.cpp:42: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse GraphDef file: EDSR_x4.pb in function 'cv::dnn::ReadTFNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie'
```

Comment: no screenshots of text please. [edit] your post and replace those with the text they contain. review [ask].

Comment: the problem is fixed

Comment: How did you fix the problem? Please post a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is really simple.
Just check if the integrity of EDSR_x4.pb is a pb file or a html, and I incorrectly used the later.
So, I download from the github again, and it worked.